# iTunes connect is telling me i don't have the icons

Tags: ios, phonegap-build

I have made an app using phonegap, HTML and javascript.  I have uploaded the app several time to iTunes connect to test and now suddenly i am getting the message that i do not have the icons in the following formats.

120 x 120
152 x 152
76 x 76

However I have the icons located in the route folder so they are at res/ios/icon/

and here is the information in my config file.

```
<platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />

    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />

    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />

    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
</platform>
```

Can anybody tell me if i have done this wrong?  I am currently using build.phonegap to build the apps.

Comment: add those image to Xcode project and submit to App Store . the above file will add files to phone gap folder only

Comment: The problem i have is this was built using html and javascript in a html editor as its a very simple app, and i can't import that i don't think in to xcode